# Using $(this) inside a setInterval in jQuery

Tags: jquery, this, setinterval

I am using this code inside a jQuery plugin:

```
setInterval(function() {                        
   localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");
   var data = $(this).serializeArray();
   console.log($(this));
   $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
      localStorage.setItem(obj.name, obj.value);
   });
   console.log('saved');
   console.log(localStorage);                       
}, 5000);

if (localStorage.getItem("flag") == "set") {
   alert("This form has saved data!");
   var data = $(this).serializeArray();
   console.log($(this));
   $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
      $("[name='" + obj.name +"']").val(localStorage.getItem(obj.name));
   });                      
}
```

Now strangely, the first `$(this)` contains the form (which the plugin is ran on), but the second `$(this)` contains `DOMWindow`. How come the two `$(this)` contain different things? Is it because the first is inside a `setInterval`?

Comment: yes, also note that `this` is overwritten by JQuery in many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use a simple closure, or use `$.proxy`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

```
var repeat = function() {                        
    localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    .......
}

setInterval($.proxy(repeat, $("#form")), 500);
```

Something like that...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have an anonymous function (a function without a name) in your `setInterval` declaration which creates its own scope.

The first `console.log($(this))` will have access to anything global or anything set within itself and the second `console.log($(this))` will have access only to global variables (and as you've found out, `this` in the global scope is the `window` object).

Answer (score 2):

It's not that it's inside `setInterval` but rather that it's inside that anonymous function.

The first `$(this)` is in the scope of the anonymous function. The second `$(this)` is in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a reference to the current object. It represents the context of a function. The default reference is the global one (in our case the `window` object).
Because the `setInterval` callback is being executed in the global scope, `this` will always point to the window object.
Here are some examples that illustrate the connection between `this` and the scope :

```
var a = "window";
function f(){
    console.log(this.a);
}
f();// scope = window
var obj = {a:'object',f:f};
obj.f();// scope = object
```