# jQuery traversing the DOM using $(this) as a starting point inside setInterval/setTimeOut function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, setinterval, dom-traversal

I've been trying to understand how to (in jQuery) traverse the DOM using $(this) as a starting point inside a setInterval/setTimeOut function and have come across some behavior I have found baffling.

It doesn't seem to be possible to traverse the DOM  using $(this) as a starting point inside a setInterval/setTimeOut function

Why is that?
jQuery/javaScript people - get on that.

**Sample code to illustrate the behaviour:**

**jQuery:**

```
// set this code anywhere (inside/outside - document.ready/named-function/...) and run it
var autoTimer = setInterval(function(){
    // INSERT EXAMPLE TEST-CODE FROM BELOW HERE
}, 10000)
```

**Test code tried:**

```
// from inside the setInterval/setTimeOut function above
// if $(this)
if($(this).length !== 0) {
    alert('hello');
} // alerts hello

// from inside the setInterval/setTimeOut function above
// if html-tag (body/head/html)
if($('body').length !== 0) {
    alert('hello');
} // alerts hello

// from inside the setInterval/setTimeOut function above
// if className
if($('.className').length !== 0) {
    alert('hello');
} // alerts hello

// from inside the setInterval/setTimeOut function above
// if id
if($('#id').length !== 0) {
    alert('hello');
} // alerts hello
```

So it finds specific elements inside the document just fine and apart from $(this) you can then traverse the DOM from there

ie.

```
// from inside the setInterval/setTimeOut function above
if ($('.className').find(something).length !== 0)... // works just fine
```

The problem comes when you want to use $(this) as a starting point for traversing

**Traversing test code tried using $(this) as a starting point:**

```
// from inside the setInterval/setTimeOut function above
// traversing up the DOM
if($(this).parents('body').length !== 0) {
    alert('hello');
} // no alert (same with closest/parentsUntil/etc up the DOM)

// from inside the setInterval/setTimeOut function above
// traversing sideways in the DOM
if($(this).siblings('body').length !== 0) {
    alert('hello');
} // no alert (same with next/prev/etc sideways in the DOM)

// from inside the setInterval/setTimeOut function above
// traversing down the DOM
if($(this).find('body').length !== 0) {
    alert('hello');
} // no alert (same with children down the DOM)
```

So starting from $(this) 'body' (or anything else for that matter) doesn't seem to exist anywhere (up/down/sideways) which is not true from any other starting point from above

**I also tried using a named global function as in:**

```
// set outside/inside document.ready
function testCode() {
    // INSERT EXAMPLE TRAVERSING TEST-CODE FROM ABOVE HERE
}

// set this code anywhere (inside/outside - document.ready/named-function/...) and run it
var autoTimer = setInterval(testCode, 10000) // no alert

// set this code anywhere (inside/outside - document.ready/named-function/...) and run it
var autoTimer = setInterval(function(){
    testCode();
}, 10000) // no alert
```

**So to re-iterate my question:**
Why does it seem impossible in jQuery to traverse the DOM (up/down/sideways) inside a setInterval/setTimeOut using $(this) as a starting point?

And what are possible hacks/work-arounds/etc. for this behavior?

**Possible none-solutions for hacks/work-arounds/etc.**

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406983/using-this-inside-a-setinterval-in-jquery) using $.proxy only works if you use an older version of jQuery - but since [as this document attests](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/#jQuery-proxy-function-context) 'This API has been deprecated in jQuery 3.3'... at the moment this is not a solution.

And neither is the [bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) method since as the document attests 'As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated' and been superseded by the [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) method (but I can't see how I would use .on() here to any effect - but maybe that's just due to my lack of imagination).

Comment: Please show us the actual code that's exhibiting the problem. You've shown us a lot of code, but none of it actually has `this` inside a `setTimeout`. It's hard to show you how to remedy your code if you haven't actually shown it to us.

Comment: I tried make it more general because the behaviour baffled me and I wanted and more general underlying explanation for why it was not working as intended (got that in accepted answer below + a use case for getting actual code to work) but that was why the more general code supplied (oh and it was setInterval and not setTimeout - though I suspect the answer would be the same for both) :) - but per suggestion an edit was added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic `this` scoping problem and has little to do with jQuery.

The most straightforward approach is to assign `this` to another variable *outside* of the callback:

```js
var that = this;

setInterval(function () {
    $(that).parents();
}, 1000);
```

If you don't care about IE, or if you have a build process, you can use an arrow function, which uses `this` from the scope outside it:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    $(this).parents();
}, 1000);
```

My personal preference is to avoid the use of `this` entirely because of all its cockamamie behavior that's giving you so much grief. It's not clear from your examples where your `this` value is coming from, but here are some ways you can avoid it:

```js
// inside .each()
$('a').each(function (_, el) {
    $(el).parents();
});

// inside event handler
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    $(event.target).parents();
});
```

Comment: Nice... that worked exactly as intended... and I'll be looking into your alternatives - but thank you so much... you have no idea how many hours I have spent on this either searching/reading and trying out suggested solutions gets my upvote and checkmark :)